# Python NotImplemented constant

Tags: python

Looking through `decimal.py`, it uses `NotImplemented` in many special methods. e.g.

```
class A(object):
    def __lt__(self, a):
        return NotImplemented

    def __add__(self, a):
        return NotImplemented
```

The [Python docs say](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html):

> **NotImplemented**
>
> Special value which can be returned by the “rich comparison”
>   special methods (`__eq__()`, `__lt__()`,
>   and friends), to indicate that the
>   comparison is not implemented with
>   respect to the other type.

It doesn't talk about other special methods and neither does it describe the behavior.

It seems to be a magic object which if returned from other special methods raises `TypeError`, and in “rich comparison” special methods does nothing.

e.g.

```
print A() < A()
```

prints `True`, but

```
print A() + 1
```

raises `TypeError`, so I am curious as to what's going on and what is the usage/behavior of NotImplemented.

Comment: All Correct.  You have completely describe NotImplemented.  What's the question?

Comment: my question was that if in doc, it specially mentions “rich comparison” special methods, other methods should ignore it, after all it is just another object, i could not find doc explaining general behavior or how to handle NotImplemented

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`NotImplemented` allows you to indicate that a comparison between the two given operands has not been implemented (rather than indicating that the comparison is valid, but yields `False`, for the two operands).

From the [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules):

> For objects x and y, first `x.__op__(y)`
> is tried. If this is not implemented
> or returns NotImplemented,
> `y.__rop__(x)` is tried. If this is also
> not implemented or returns
> NotImplemented, a TypeError exception
> is raised. But see the following
> exception:

> Exception to the previous
> item: if the left operand is an
> instance of a built-in type or a
> new-style class, and the right operand
> is an instance of a proper subclass of
> that type or class and overrides the
> base's `__rop__()` method, the right
> operand's `__rop__()` method is tried
> before the left operand's `__op__()`
> method. This is done so that a
> subclass can completely override
> binary operators. Otherwise, the left
> operand's `__op__()` method would always
> accept the right operand: when an
> instance of a given class is expected,
> an instance of a subclass of that
> class is always acceptable.

Comment: ok, so in general behavior is if return value is NotImplemented try something else, if that is not possible raise TypeError

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use it in other contexts, like, say, a dictionary mapping between different types?

Comment: The link is broken, could you update the link? I want to see the source page.

Answer (score 7):

It actually has the same meaning when returned from `__add__` as from `__lt__`, the difference is Python 2.x is trying other ways of comparing the objects before giving up. Python 3.x does raise a TypeError. In fact, Python can try other things for `__add__` as well, look at `__radd__` and (though I'm fuzzy on it) `__coerce__`.

```
# 2.6
>>> class A(object):
...   def __lt__(self, other):
...     return NotImplemented
>>> A() < A()
True

# 3.1
>>> class A(object):
...   def __lt__(self, other):
...     return NotImplemented
>>> A() < A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: A() < A()
```

See [Ordering Comparisions (3.0 docs)](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you return it from `__add__` it will behave like the object has no `__add__` method, and raise a `TypeError`.

If you return `NotImplemented` from a rich comparison function, Python will behave like the method wasn't implemented, that is, it will defer to using `__cmp__`.