# Abstract base class: raise NotImplementedError() in `__init__.py`?

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm warns me `Call to __init__ of super class is missed`

```
class AbstractBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class RealChild(AbstractBase):
    def __init__(self):
        #super(RealChild, self).__init__() ####
        print('do stuff')

child=RealChild()
```

But if I call it, the class `AbstractBase` will raise `NotImplementedError`.

I am a sheep and don't know how to proceed :-)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972631/python-abstract-classes-how-to-discourage-instantiation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something kind-of ugly and check the type of `self` in the abstract type’s initializer to make sure that it was subtyped:

```
class AbstractBase (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        if type(self) is AbstractBase:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

I think a more “normal” approach would be to simply not expose the abstract base type and expect users not to create it.

Comment: How can I "not expose the abstract base type"? Other developers need to subclass it.

Comment: Developers yes, but users don’t. So only make it available to developers who know it shouldn’t be instanced on its own. In general, don’t go too far to enforce rules, but just document it clearly and expect people to do it correctly.

Comment: I still don't get it. My users know how to use a web browser. The don't know that Python is a programming language. I guess "don't expose the abstract base type" does not work in my case.

Answer (score 8):

You might consider [using the `abc` Abstract Base Class module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973879/5265467) to mark `__init__` as abstract, and then go ahead and invoke the superclass `__init__` from the subclass (and, as [DorElias suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372250/5265467), give the superclass `__init__` a trivial implementation of `pass`):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class AbstractBase(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod  # This method must be overridden...
    def __init__(self):
        print("...but can still be called via super by subclasses have shared construction logic")
        pass


class RealChild(AbstractBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # Won't do anything, UNTIL the day you decide all subclasses of AbstractBase need shared logic
        print('do stuff')


child = RealChild()
```

If you try to instantiate via `parent = AbstractBase()` or `parent = AbstractBase.__new__(AbstractBase)`, you'll get an error:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class AbstractBase with abstract methods **init**

So you've got your uninstantiable abstract safety, but at the same time you are still well set up to alter all child class construction by altering base class construction, as is right and proper.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If the intent is to have an ABC, be explicit about it -- raising an exception in the constructor is not the way to do this.

Comment: Using `@abstractmethod` is better, but calling the super `__init__` just to avoid the Pycharm warning feels wrong. The super `__init__` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the abstract class replace the exception in the **init** function with

```
pass
```

This exception is used to prevent you from initializing new instance of the abstract class (it is abstract, so you can't) 
So either use 'pass'  or don't listen to pycharm and don't call super

Comment: Technically, the exception prevents you from initializing a new object, not creating it. `a = A.__new__(A)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377132/5214931) by @Bryant correctly explains that you should use `@abstractmethod` instead of manually raising a `NotImplementedError`.

This allows you to call the super `__init__`, but it doesn't necessarily mean that you should, since it still doesn't do anything. It's a matter of personal taste, and Pycharm is wrong to issue a warning over it.

So my alternative answer is: ignore Pycharm and hope that they fix this some day.