# Methods regarding Class Rational python

Tags: class, oop, python-3.x, rational-number

i wrote the two methods, i still see no difference between the two methods..my class works fine so far , but since the methods are written the same, i still can't understand why when i do : x+1 it calls add , and 1+x it calls radd ?

```
  def __add__(self,other):
    assert isinstance(other,(Rational,int,str))
    other=Rational(other)
    n = self.n * other.d + self.d * other.n
    d = self.d * other.d
    return Rational(n, d)

def __radd__(self,other):
    assert isinstance(other,(Rational,int,str))
    other=Rational(other)
    n =self.d * other.n + other.d * self.n
    d=other.d * self.d
    return Rational(n, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

When Python evaluates `X+Y`, it first calls

```
X.__add__(Y)
```

[if that returns NotImplemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1062096/190597), then Python calls

```
Y.__radd__(X)
```

---

This example demonstrates when `__radd__` versus `__add__` is called:

```
class Commuter:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
    def __add__(self,other):
        print 'Commuter add', self.val, other
    def __radd__(self,other):
        print 'Commuter radd', self.val, other

x = Commuter(88)
y = Commuter(99)
x+1
# Commuter add 88 1

1+y
# Commuter radd 99 1

x+y
# Commuter add 88 <__main__.Commuter instance at 0xb7d2cfac>
```

---

In this case:

```
In [3]: (1).__add__(y)
Out[3]: NotImplemented
```

So `y.__radd__(1)` gets called.

Comment: when i run my class without __radd__it won't give me , but when i do run it ,it allows me to run it normally,so i guess it means this is alright?
    def __add__(self,other):
        assert isinstance(other,(Rational,int,str))
        other=Rational(other)
        n = self.n * other.d + self.d * other.n
        d = self.d * other.d
        return Rational(n, d)
    def __radd__(self,other):
        assert isinstance(other,(Rational,int,str))
        other=Rational(other)
        n =self.d * other.n + other.d * self.n
        d=other.d * self.d
        return Rational(n, d)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, and it's really hard to read code in the comments. Please edit your original question, add the code there, using the `{}` button so the code gets formatted properly.

Comment: You are defining `__add__` and `__radd__` for the class `Rational`. `x` is an instance of `Rational`, but `1` is not. `1` is an `int`. The `int` class has its own `__add__` and `__radd__` methods. `1+x` causes `(1).__add__(x)` to be called. That returns `NotImplemented`, which causes `x.__radd__(1)` to be called. (By the way, since your `__add__` and `__radd__` methods are identical, you can just say `__radd__ = __add__` instead of defining `__radd__` with `def __radd__(self, other):` ....)

Comment: im having a slight problem, lets say im using __add__ , and i add a rational number to a rational number it doesn't work, if its int , then all is well..as for __sub__ its the other way round, it works well when its Rational - Rational, but when its Rational - int, it doesn't work..what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given the expression `a + b`, if object `a` implements `__add__` it will be called with `b`:

```
a.__add__(b)
```

However, if a does not implement `__add__` and `b` implements `__radd__` (read as "right-add"), then `b.__radd__` will be called with `a`:

```
b.__radd__(a)
```

The documentation explaining this is [here](http://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__).