# Extend python build-in class: float

Tags: python, class

I would like to change the

```
float.__str__
```

function of the build in float type (python 2)

I tried to extend this class.

```
class SuperFloat(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'I am' + self.__repr__()
```

However, when I add it it becomes a normal float

```
egg = SuperFloat(5)
type(egg+egg)
```

returns float

My ultimate goal is that also

```
egg += 5
```

stays a superfloat

Answer (score 6):

You will need to override the "magic methods" on your type: `__add__`, `__sub__`, etc.  See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for a list of these methods.  unutbu's answer shows how to do this for `__add__` and `__radd__`, but there are a lot more you will have to override if you want your subclass to be substitutable for the builtin type in any situation.  [This page](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/739295) has some suggestions on how to make some of that work easier.

Comment: The referenced page is dead. Here is and [archive.org copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20090629065927/http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/739295) or the [official python archive](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-April/thread.html#683359)

Answer (score 5):

```
class SuperFloat(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'I am ' + self.__repr__()
    def __add__(self, other):
        return SuperFloat(super(SuperFloat, self).__add__(other))
    __radd__ = __add__
```

---

```
In [63]: type(5+egg)
Out[63]: __main__.SuperFloat

In [64]: type(egg+5)
Out[64]: __main__.SuperFloat

In [65]: type(egg+egg)
Out[65]: __main__.SuperFloat

In [67]: egg += 5

In [69]: type(egg)
Out[69]: __main__.SuperFloat
```

Comment: What is the difference between `__radd__` and `__add__`?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: `5+egg` calls `(5).__add__(egg)` which returns `NotImplemented`. This causes `egg.__radd__(5)` to be called. This gives `egg` a chance to handle the addition. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1062096/190597.

Comment: This will only fix the problem for `+` specifically, but it seems clear from the question that he wants his subclass to "act like a float" for all operations, which would require overriding many more methods.

Comment: I think you are reading more into the question than is actually there. The OP says "my ultimate goal is that also `egg += 5` stays a superfloat."

Comment: @unutbu: Heh, maybe, but I find it somewhat unlikely that the entire point of the subclass is just to execute that single line of code.  He starts off by saying his original goal was to override `float.__str__`, and that override will not take full effect without overriding all the math magic methods.

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe so, but basic code samples can be invaluable when learning how to do that. I especially gave a +1 for the `__radd__ = __add__`, which I would not have thought to do. The answer you gave completely leapfrogs the basics of overriding the magic methods and I feel like that is less helpful than this.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Information on how to more fully subclass `float` is great, but I don't see what I can do about. I could subsume your answer into mine, but I don't think that is polite behavior.